# How to pass a List of String to a Object, when every string value have a key=value

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object, arraylist

I'm new to JavaScript and would like to know if there is a better way to transform a list string to an object.

From a service I get the following list, but I need to transform it to an object to be able to process it i.e. from this list

```
 let objString = ['name=Antonio', 'phone=123-2312-3123', 'address=Paraiso'];
```

I need to pass it to an obj

```
    objString = { 
      'name': 'Antonio',
      'phone': '123-2312-3123',
      'address': 'Paraiso',
     }
```

I can't find a method or something simpler that I already have integrated JS instead of doing a lot of loops.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Map the `objString` array to a pairs of `[key, value]` by splitting each string, and convert the array to an object using `Object.fromEntries()`:

```js
const objString = ['name=Antonio', 'phone=123-2312-3123', 'address=Paraiso']

const result = Object.fromEntries(objString.map(str => str.split('=')))

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 3):

You string structure is pretty specific to have something built-in for it, but I don't understand the

> instead of doing a lot of loops

It's just one loop, you just have to parse the array and store the key-value pairs in an object:

```js
const objString = {}
const array = ['name=Antonio', 'phone=123-2312-3123', 'address=Paraiso']
array.forEach(el => {
    // Split it in 2 by "="
    const parts = el.split('=')
    objString[parts[0]] = parts[1]
})
console.log(objString)
```